# I'm working with counting table and have some problem. How to fix 'Fatal error: String index is out of bounds'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working with counting label String. When I run my project all my text shows and at the end it crashes with:

> 'Fatal error: String index is out of bounds'

on the line:

```
startText += String(endText[index])
```

in the `handleUpdate` method.

I don't understand why.

```
class AboutViewController: BaseListController {
    let countingLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .white
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(countingLabel)
        countingLabel.frame = view.frame

        let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(handleUpdate))
        displayLink.add(to: .main, forMode: .default)
    }

    var startText = " "
    let endText = "Hey! I need your help..."
    var startValue = 0

    @objc func handleUpdate(){
        let endTextValue = endText.count - 1

        let index = endText.index(endText.startIndex, offsetBy: startValue)

        self.countingLabel.text = "\(startText)"
        // Error on the following line:
        startText += String(endText[index])
        startValue += 1

        if startValue > endTextValue{
            startText = endText
        }
        print(endTextValue)
    }

    let animationStartDate = Date()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `handleUpdate` on a `CADisplayLink`, it will continue to be called after `startValue` has been incremented beyond the length of the string.  You do have a check for `startValue > endTextValue` but this is *after* you have already tried to index using `startValue`, so you get a crash.

You need to `remove` the `CADisplayLink` handler once its job is done, which means you need to keep a reference to it.

```
var startText = ""
let endText = "Hey! I need your help..."
var startValue = 0
var displayLink: CADisplayLink?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(countingLabel)
    countingLabel.frame = view.frame

    self.displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(handleUpdate))
    self.displayLink!.add(to: .main, forMode: .default)
}

@objc func handleUpdate(){
    guard startValue < endText.count else {
        self.displayLink?.invalidate()
        self.displayLink = nil
        return
    }

    let index = endText.index(endText.startIndex, offsetBy: startValue)

    startText += String(endText[index])
    self.countingLabel.text = "\(startText)"
    startValue += 1

    let animationStartDate = Date()
}
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, you can click on the tick to accept it.